# mvn sourceanalyzer plug-in not running scan

Tags: maven, fortify

I am using maven with a Fortify360 plug-in to analyze the source code.  The sca:translate step runs fine and seems to generate the correct sca-translate-java.txt files, but the sca:scan step does not actually run the scan on any of the sub-projects.

I am given no reason why, just error message like :

> *** Skipping scan of sub-project

I am new to Fortify. Anyone have experience with this, and have some ideas for why it could be skipping the scans?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using aggregated profile?

Comment: Yes, the plug-in is in the parent pom.

Comment: I'm not using a profile for running the scan though. It is run against the entire project

Comment: Can you show configuration of the `maven-sca-plugin`?

Answer (score 1):

If your projects are inheriting from a top level pom, you need to also use the -Dsca.toplevel=foo parameter, and also you need to set the build ID manually.

So in the translate step, add the extra -D parameter to set a build id.

In the scan step, add the same -D parameter to set a build id.

Also in the scan step, add the "top level" -D parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As it is nicely self-documented in sources here [ScanMojo](https://github.com/dougmorato/fortify_maven_plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fortify/ps/maven/plugin/sca/ScanMojo.java) if you want aggregated result for entire project you need to specify both                             `<buildId>...</buildId>`and `<toplevelArtifactId>...</toplevelArtifactId>` and they should match otherwise it skips sub-projects.